# use htaccess to redirect a range of urls which have parameters

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, parameters, url-rewriting

I had an email subscription for updates on my site, which I've temporarily disabled. I'm seeing hits to the site related to the subscription. The urls are very long but the first several characters are always the same. I've been trying to redirect these (at least for the time being) to a single page with some explanatory text. I've tried several things so far, but haven't been able to get the syntax correct.

BTW, I had to change the question significantly because I couldn't figure out how to satisfy the "quality standards".

EDITED TO ADD:

Incoming urls are:

**exampledomain.com/?wysija-page=1...**

I want every incoming url that matches this format - no matter what replaces the "..." - to go to:

**exampledomain.com/subscriptions**

It's a WordPress site.

Comment: We need more concrete example of original and target URLs. Don't provide them in comment, just edit your question.

Comment: Okay, edited to add some specifics. Hopefully, this is do-able and someone here can tell me the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert this rule just below `RewriteEgine` line in your WP .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)wysija-page=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /subscriptions? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: Awesome--that's perfect! Thank you, anubhava.